# What is causing my device to uninstall the application after a reboot?

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation, restart

So I have my application that I'm running, which works normally - no issues. I get it onto my device by sideloading it, as per the norm, and again the application runs just fine. One of my tests is to reboot the device and then check to see if certain info persisted - however, for some reason, whenever I reboot the device, my app is totally uninstalled. It's not in the Apps section, or on any of my tabs or screens - it's just gone. Does anyone know what could cause an app to be completely uninstalled like this from just rebooting the device? I was able to do this just fine on this device and another not too long ago, but now it seems every time I reboot one, the app's gone.

I don't believe anything we've done recently would cause this... it just started to happen. I thought it was the device itself at first, but given I've now seen two devices that lose the app after a reboot, it has to be related to something I have either in my IDE or in my app.

Any thoughts on what this could be?

Answer (score 2):

There are some possible reasons why the applications on your device uninstall.

1. The application is installed in the external SD card.
2. You have installed or reached an untrusted program that can harm your device.
3. Your device was hacked, check your Google account if there are suspicious or unknown activities/logins that can confirm that you were hacked.

How to prevent applications from getting deleted automatically after reboot?

1. Root the android phone - enables you to add new apps and remove unnecessary programs in your Android phone.
2. Convert the user app into the system app - it cannot be changed even if you delete it. So if you want to convert the user app to a system app, you need to move the app APK files to system/app manually.
3. Reboot your phone - if your device is already rooted but still uninstall apps, you should reboot it. but, you need to unroot your phone first.